# Two React-hook-form form onSubmit error, submit both when submit one

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, form-submit, react-hook-form

I have two React-hook-form in one page like this:

```
const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    getValues,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      departureDate: moment().add(1, "days"),
      adults: 2,
      children: 0,
    },
    resolver: yupResolver(booking_schema),
  });

  const { control: control2, handleSubmit: handleSubmit2 } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      name: "",
      phoneNumber: "",
      email: "",
      note: "",
    },
    resolver: yupResolver(guest_schema),
  });
```

onSubmit functions

```
 const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    setOpenModal(true);
    setDataRequest(data);
  };

  const onSubmitInfo = (data, e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(data);
    console.log(dataRequest);
  };
```

Two form

```
<Box
   component="form"
   id="bookingForm"
   autoComplete="off"
   className={classes.sidebar}
   onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
  >
...
</Box>
<Box
  id="guestForm"
  component="form"
  onSubmit={handleSubmit2(onSubmitInfo)}
  autoComplete="off"
  >
...
</Box
```

When I submit form 1, I open a modal. One form dialog (form 2) popup when I click a button in modal. But when I submit form 2, I saw the onSubmit function in form 1 running too. I googling a while and try to add **id** and **stopPropagation** but it's doesn't work.

Comment: How are you rendering the buttons that submit your forms?

Comment: @BrendanBond thank you for your clue. I realized that I put a form dialog inside form 1.

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

hide your functions in eventlistener behind function. like

```
onSubmit={() => handleSubmit2(on)},
```

can't completely understand how your components are build and functionality, so hope it will help for you

Comment: This problem is caused by my bad. Thank you for your help. Your answer helps me on another matter.